# Custom Font specified by CSS not working

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a line here where im setting the color and font size, and font family

```
literalCardNumber = string.Format("<span style=color:black;font-size:14px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLT Std Med; >" + bestCard.Info.serialNumber.ToString() + "</span>");
```

the font size and color are correct but the font change is not taking, when i inspect the element I see

```
<span style="color:black;font-size:14px;font-family:HelveticaNeueLT" std="" med;="">Pastel Green</span>
```

What should my original line be? It doesnt seem to like the spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that fonts that aren't web-standard need to be contained within quotes.

Try (I'm not sure of the exact syntax of escaping characters to load the family properly as this language isn't my forte) this...

```
literalCardNumber = string.Format("<span style=\"color:black;font-size:14px;font-family:'HelveticaNeueLT Std Med',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;\">" + bestCard.Info.serialNumber.ToString() + "</span>");
```

I added a bit more because it's highly desirable that you have a fallback for users, especially those with security settings that don't allow font downloads.

Comment: I am now getting this <span style="color:black;font-size:14px;font-family:'HelveticaNeueLT" std="" med';="">Pastel Green</span>

Comment: Please check the updated answer for proper escaping. You can also change your `@font-face` declaration so the name of the font when referenced is different.